# Inserting Empty value and number in a row postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a column, lets take A,

**A can be sometimes '5' which is a string number**

**A can also be ' ' which is empty string**

I want to insert this kind of scenario data in my postgresql table

I tried

when a = '5'

**int(a or ' ') --- > It is getting inserted as 5**

But When a = ' '

**int(a or ' ') --- > Its not able insert empty string**

I know integer can't be empty.

Also i tried to use

COALESCE(NULLIF(a,' ')) --> it says coalesce is not defined.

I want both the conditions to get satisfied to insert the data if its present , if not insert empty for the column in postgres

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The string you show in your example contains a single blank and is *not* empty. Which do you mean? Also, can you provide the complete SQL statements you tried, the response you get, and why you think this is wrong.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I  mean about the single blank string.